# In what scenarios, update-database drops and creates tables

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core in a project, and I must do an `update-database` on the production database with a new migration. Before proceeding I have to know the cases where performing `update-database` drops and recreates tables, so I don't loose any data.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, generate scripts.

> When debugging your migrations or deploying them to a production
> database, it's useful to generate a SQL script. The script can then be
> further reviewed for accuracy and tuned to fit the needs of a
> production database. The script can also be used in conjunction with a
> deployment technology.

[Migrations - Generate SQL Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#generate-sql-scripts)